# how to use markdown with django? by only in 2 tags

Tags: python, django, markdown

I want to use markdown with django.

I want to allow use bold and strike tags.
Others don't convert.

Please teach me.

Comment: You don't need markdown for that...

Answer (score 2):

Django supports Markdown, but you'll need to install the Python package: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/markup/

Comment: Sadly, 1.5 is deprecating the use of this module with an "accelerated deprecation schedule"

Comment: @LoSauer "Direct use of python markup libraries or 3rd party tag libraries is preferred to Django maintaining this functionality in the framework." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/releases/1.5/#django-contrib-markup

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [markdown2](http://code.google.com/p/python-markdown2/) for converting text to html. But if you just want to use bold and strike, maybe you should look for using directly regex/parser.

A "secure" mode is also possible in markdown2, forcing the user to use only the official markdown syntax, with ignoring the html. (making it more secure)